# Issue with the installation of flutter_launcher_icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I added the flutter package "flutter_launcher_icons" but get problems when try to use it.

My "pubspec.yaml":

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.13.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_blue: ^0.8.0
  csv: ^5.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/Logo.png" 
  adaptive_icon_background: "assets/launcher/background.png"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/launcher/foreground.png"
```

When I run "pub get" I get this (looks OK):

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in ble_thms...                           790ms
Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I try to run the "flutter_launcher_icons" I get this:

```
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools>flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
Could not find package "flutter_launcher_icons". Did you forget to add a dependency?
pub finished with exit code 65
```

When I try to install "flutter_launcher_icons via terminal its the same:

```
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools>flutter pub get flutter_launcher_icons
Running "flutter pub get" in ....                                  894ms

C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools>flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
Could not find package "flutter_launcher_icons". Did you forget to add a dependency?
pub finished with exit code 65
```

How can I solve this problem to use the package "flutter_launcerh_icons"? I also already tried "pub upgrade" and "pub outdated".

Answer (score 22):

Add the dependency **`flutter_launcher_icons`** like so:

```
flutter pub add flutter_launcher_icons
```

then:

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issues in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The dependency is dev dependency, so it must go under dev_dependencies list.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

Dev dependency are not necessarily ran on "flutter run", but rather with specific command, like:

> flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main -f "pubspec.yaml'

Please refer to [installation guide on pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons#book-guide)

Answer (score 3):

You should be try to use below dependency:

```
flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
```

Below is your `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"

flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icon/Logo.png" 
  android: true
  ios: true
```

1. Prepare an app icon for the specified path. e.g. icon/icon.png
2. Execute command on the terminal to Create app icons:

   ```
    flutter pub get

    flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
   ```

Comment: Ok, some progress.  I am now getting at least an error: ".... So, because wthms_ble depends on both flutter_blue ^0.8.0 and flutter_launcher_icons ^0.8.0, version solving failed...".  So I downgraded also flutter_blue to ^0.7.3 and again I get no error, but when  try to run "flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main" it can not find "flutter_launcher_icons"

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that there is a problem with the flutter_tools  and the dependence on "image"

```
C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools>flutter pub add flutter_launcher_icons
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because flutter_launcher_icons <0.4.0 requires SDK version >=1.20.1 <2.0.0 and flutter_launcher_icons >=0.4.0 <0.7.1 depends on image ^2.0.0, flutter_launcher_icons <0.7.1 requires image ^2.0.0.
And because flutter_launcher_icons >=0.7.1 <0.9.0 depends on yaml ^2.1.15 and flutter_launcher_icons >=0.9.0 depends on args 2.0.0, every version of flutter_launcher_icons requires args 2.0.0 or image ^2.0.0 or yaml ^2.1.15.
And because flutter_tools depends on both args 2.1.0 and yaml 3.1.0, every version of flutter_launcher_icons requires image ^2.0.0.
So, because flutter_tools depends on both image ^3.0.2 and flutter_launcher_icons any, version solving failed.
```

Can I "downgrade" somehow the "flutter_tools" ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

I somehow changed the path in the Android Studio Console to "C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools".
So I changed it back to the project path "C:\src\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\my_flutter_project".

Now it is working.

Clumsy mistake from my side. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and i find that i wrote `laucher` instead of `launcher` in my command line

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem, type this command in the code editor terminal:

```
flutter pub add package_name
```

or, if it already exist:

```
flutter pub upgrade package_name
```

Hopefully it will solve the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the same error you have, and it was something so simple that many of us do not realize it sometimes.

- Verify that the terminal is in your project folder.
- Try putting flutter_launcher_icons: any in the dev_dependencies: section like in the image.
- Verify correct indentation in pubspec.yaml

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrLSq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

> flutter clean

then

> flutter pub get

solved it.

Answer (score 0):

## its same hapend with me but i just change in pubspec.yaml

```yaml
flutter_launcher_icons:
   android: true
   image_path: "assets/images/logo.jpeg"
   min_sdk_android: 21
```

to

```yaml
flutter_icons:
   android: true
   image_path: "assets/images/logo.jpeg"
   min_sdk_android: 21
```

its work for me
its not updated in pub.dev

Comment: According to the [flutter_launcher_icons](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) package, `flutter_icons` key is deprecated and `flutter_launcher_icons` should be used.